# Binary Bomb Lab- Phase 3

Tags: assembly

So I'm struggling understanding this phase of a binary bomb lab that I have to do for class. I see that I need more than 2 inputs  for the function to work, but it begins to get really muddy after that.

Here's the assembly code for phase 3:

```
   0x0000000000400ff7 <+0>:     sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x0000000000400ffb <+4>:     lea    0xc(%rsp),%r8
   0x0000000000401000 <+9>:     lea    0x7(%rsp),%rcx
   0x0000000000401005 <+14>:    lea    0x8(%rsp),%rdx
   0x000000000040100a <+19>:    mov    $0x402776,%esi
   0x000000000040100f <+24>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000401014 <+29>:    callq  0x400cb0 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>  //taking in input
   0x0000000000401019 <+34>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax //checks if more than 2 inputs appear
   0x000000000040101c <+37>:    jg     0x401023 <phase_3+44> //jump if greater than 2 inputs
   0x000000000040101e <+39>:    callq  0x401741 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401023 <+44>:    cmpl   $0x7,0x8(%rsp) //checks if first input value is less than 7
   0x0000000000401028 <+49>:    ja     0x401120 <phase_3+297>
   0x000000000040102e <+55>:    mov    0x8(%rsp),%eax
   0x0000000000401032 <+59>:    jmpq   *0x402790(,%rax,8) //jumps to certain memory address based on first input.
   0x0000000000401039 <+66>:    mov    $0x75,%eax
   0x000000000040103e <+71>:    cmpl   $0x18d,0xc(%rsp) //i think this is one of the switch cases that  <+59> jumps to.
   0x0000000000401046 <+79>:    je     0x40112a <phase_3+307>
   0x000000000040104c <+85>:    callq  0x401741 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401051 <+90>:    mov    $0x75,%eax
   0x0000000000401056 <+95>:    jmpq   0x40112a <phase_3+307>
   0x000000000040105b <+100>:   mov    $0x68,%eax
   0x0000000000401060 <+105>:   cmpl   $0xd0,0xc(%rsp)
   0x0000000000401068 <+113>:   je     0x40112a <phase_3+307>//another switch case
   0x000000000040106e <+119>:   callq  0x401741 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401073 <+124>:   mov    $0x68,%eax
   0x0000000000401078 <+129>:   jmpq   0x40112a <phase_3+307>
   0x000000000040107d <+134>:   mov    $0x79,%eax
   0x0000000000401082 <+139>:   cmpl   $0x2fd,0xc(%rsp)
   0x000000000040108a <+147>:   je     0x40112a <phase_3+307>//another switch case
   0x0000000000401090 <+153>:   callq  0x401741 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401095 <+158>:   mov    $0x79,%eax
   0x000000000040109a <+163>:   jmpq   0x40112a <phase_3+307>
   0x000000000040109f <+168>:   mov    $0x68,%eax
   0x00000000004010a4 <+173>:   cmpl   $0x3da,0xc(%rsp)
   0x00000000004010ac <+181>:   je     0x40112a <phase_3+307>/all another switch case
   0x00000000004010ae <+183>:   callq  0x401741 <explode_bomb>
   0x00000000004010b3 <+188>:   mov    $0x68,%eax
   0x00000000004010b8 <+193>:   jmp    0x40112a <phase_3+307>
   0x00000000004010ba <+195>:   mov    $0x71,%eax
   0x00000000004010bf <+200>:   cmpl   $0x375,0xc(%rsp)
   0x00000000004010c7 <+208>:   je     0x40112a <phase_3+307>// another switch case
   0x00000000004010c9 <+210>:   callq  0x401741 <explode_bomb>
   0x00000000004010ce <+215>:   mov    $0x71,%eax
   0x00000000004010d3 <+220>:   jmp    0x40112a <phase_3+307>
   0x00000000004010d5 <+222>:   mov    $0x77,%eax
   0x00000000004010da <+227>:   cmpl   $0x53,0xc(%rsp)
   0x00000000004010df <+232>:   je     0x40112a <phase_3+307>// another switch case
   0x00000000004010e1 <+234>:   callq  0x401741 <explode_bomb>
   0x00000000004010e6 <+239>:   mov    $0x77,%eax
   0x00000000004010eb <+244>:   jmp    0x40112a <phase_3+307>
   0x00000000004010ed <+246>:   mov    $0x62,%eax
   0x00000000004010f2 <+251>:   cmpl   $0x67,0xc(%rsp)
   0x00000000004010f7 <+256>:   je     0x40112a <phase_3+307>// another switch case

   0x00000000004010f9 <+258>:   callq  0x401741 <explode_bomb>
   0x00000000004010fe <+263>:   mov    $0x62,%eax
   0x0000000000401103 <+268>:   jmp    0x40112a <phase_3+307>
   0x0000000000401105 <+270>:   mov    $0x61,%eax
   0x000000000040110a <+275>:   cmpl   $0xd7,0xc(%rsp)
   0x0000000000401112 <+283>:   je     0x40112a <phase_3+307>// another switch case

   0x0000000000401114 <+285>:   callq  0x401741 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401119 <+290>:   mov    $0x61,%eax
   0x000000000040111e <+295>:   jmp    0x40112a <phase_3+307>
   0x0000000000401120 <+297>:   callq  0x401741 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401125 <+302>:   mov    $0x77,%eax
   0x000000000040112a <+307>:   cmp    0x7(%rsp),%al
   0x000000000040112e <+311>:   je     0x401135 <phase_3+318>// another switch case

   0x0000000000401130 <+313>:   callq  0x401741 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401135 <+318>:   add    $0x18,%rsp // add 18 to final val of rsp
```

I apologize for the quantity of code but I am unfamiliar with assembly and am really struggling to understand where the loop is and what function is being performed by this code.

EDIT: I looked at it for a while and I finally found that the inputs are meant to be in -int char int- form. Additionally, the size of the code is attributed to the fact that depending on the value of the first int input, the value of the other two potential keys change. The main problem I am now having is that I cannot really follow how the first input is being used to generate the other ones.

Comment: Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler labels branch targets.  I found it handy when doing a bomb lab.  See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: comment the code up until you get lost.  It's a lot easier to see where your comments don't match the code than to solve it from scratch.  Do that and I'll change my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Whether your questions are homework or not, it is best to be more specific. With that said, keep [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) in mind when it comes to homework in any stack exchange.

To help you with your problem, I strongly suggest you use a breakpoint on the bombs to stop them from exploding at all. You can try either for the same effect:

```
break *0x000000000040101e
break *main+39
```

Furthermore, break points are also nice to use in order to test out any theories you may have without fear of exploding a bomb. I recommend you use the gdb debugger to your advantage and google around for everything else! See [here](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~apt/cs577_2008/gdb.pdf) for more useful commands.

Comment: I'd suggest single-stepping instructions, after setting a breakpoint at some early point.  `layout reg` is great for showing which reg was changed by the last insn.